# Inconsistent view count between question page and search results page?

Tags: bug

When I search "moose" in the search engine I see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574089/the-moose-must-flow-but-how) has 3k views:

[image]

When I open up the question's page I see 4k views:

[image]

Is this some kind of difference in rounding rules, or something else?

Comment: By hovering the cursor over the "3k views" you can see the exact number.  Currently they are 37 apart.  One is led to suspect the interfaces are hitting different versions of the database.  This is a question for the main meta site because it almost surely applies to every SE site.  Have you searched there for an answer?